# process [kthreaddi] is consuming almost 100% CPU and high memory in ubuntu server

Tags: laravel, ubuntu-16.04, serve

[image: process kthreaddi is consuming almost 100% CPU and high usage of memory]

process [kthreaddi] is consuming almost 100% CPU and high usage of memory on ubuntu based server